# Angular 2 change detection through event emitter consumes massive CPU time

Tags: javascript, performance, angular, angular2-services

I noticed that my Angular 2 app gets painfully slow after a while of usage.

I profiled the CPU time and found out that there are massive change detection executions going on.

CPU profile right after page load ...

[image: CPU profile after page load]

... compared to the CPU profile after using the page for a while.

[image: CPU profile after using the page for a while]

I used a lot of `EventEmitter` in different services to communicate between a lot of components.

After testing a while it seems that the emitter for the window scroll event causes a big part of the heavy load.

The CPU profile after using the page for a while *without* emitting scroll events:

[image: CPU profile without emiting scroll event]

Here the implementation of the service:

```
@Injectable()
export class WindowService {

  @Output() scrolled$: EventEmitter<WindowScrolled> = new EventEmitter();

  private scrollDebounceTime = 25;

  constructor() {
    this.addEvent(window, 'scroll', this.debounce((event) => {
      this.scrolled$.emit(new WindowScrolled(window.scrollX, window.scrollY));
    }, this.scrollDebounceTime));
  }

  // ... other functions
}
```

## Questions

1. How can I debug the change detection calls to see where are they applied to?
2. What else can cause so many change detection calls?
3. If I'm using the `EventEmitter` wrong, how do I use it correctly?

## Edit 1

In addition I post the grid tree component, because the changes might be caused by the recursive tree structure my components build.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'hierarchy-grid-tree',
  moduleId: __moduleName, // use `__moduleName` from System.js for relative styleUrls and templateUrls
  styleUrls : [`hierarchy-grid.css`],
  template: `<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item" *ngFor="#node of nodes; #i = index" [ngClass]="{'intermediate': node.has()}" [ngStyle]="{'flex-grow': flexGrow(node), 'flex-basis': visRepConf.nodeWidth+'px', 'order': (i+1)}">
      <hierarchy-node [node]="node" [visRepConf]="visRepConf" #hnInstance></hierarchy-node>
      <hierarchy-grid-tree [nodes]="node.children()" [visRepConf]="visRepConf" [show-depth]="showDepth" [curr-depth]="currDepth + 1" *ngIf="(showDepth === -1 || currDepth < depth) && node.has() && !hnInstance.isCollapsed"></hierarchy-grid-tree>
    </div>
  </div>`,
  providers:  [],
  directives: [HierarchyGridTreeComponent, HierarchyNodeComponent]
})
export class HierarchyGridTreeComponent {

  @Input() nodes: Array<Node> = [];

  @Input() visRepConf:VisRepresentationConfig;

  @Input('show-depth') showDepth = -1;

  @Input('curr-depth') currDepth = 1;

  constructor() {

  }

  flexGrow(node) {
    if(node.has()) {
      return node.numChildrenRecursive();
    }
    return 'auto';
  }
}

// see html demo at http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgqjPP
@Component({
  selector: 'hierarchy-grid',
  moduleId: __moduleName, // use `__moduleName` from System.js for relative styleUrls and templateUrls
  styleUrls : [`hierarchy-grid.css`],
  template: `<div class="color-{{color}}" [ngClass]="{'selects-infra':selectsInfra}" (click)="selectInfra($event)">
    <p *ngIf="showInfraTitle" class="title">{{title}}</p>
    <hierarchy-node *ngIf="external" [node]="external" [visRepConf]="visRepConf"></hierarchy-node>
    <hierarchy-grid-tree [nodes]="nodes" [visRepConf]="visRepConf"></hierarchy-grid-tree>
  </div>`,
  providers:  [],
  directives: [HierarchyGridTreeComponent, HierarchyNodeComponent]
})
export class HierarchyGridComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @Input('vis-config') visConfig:string = '';

  @Input('infra') infra:Infrastructure;

  @Input('show-external') showExternal:boolean = false;

  @Input('show-infra-title') showInfraTitle:boolean = false;

  @Input('selects-infra') selectsInfra:boolean = false;

  private visRepConf:VisRepresentationConfig;

  private external:ExternalNode;

  private nodes:Array<Node>;

  private color:string;

  private title:string;

  constructor(private nodeSelection:NodeSelectionService) {
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes) {
    if(changes.infra !== undefined && this.infra !== undefined) {
      this.visRepConf = this.infra.visConfig.get(this.visConfig);

      this.nodes = [this.infra.root];

      if(this.showExternal) {
        this.external = this.infra.external;
      }

      this.color = this.infra.color;
      this.title = this.infra.name;
    }
  }

  selectInfra($event) {
    if(this.selectsInfra) {
      this.nodeSelection.infra = this.infra;
    }
  }
}
```

The resulting hierarchy grid:

[image: Hierarchy grid]

Comment: I think for these kind of cases a full repro would be awesome. What if you found a bug that cause memory leaks? Before assuming anything, I would recommend you to stop using EventEmitter inside services, its purpose is to communicate components so use Observables directly, and to avoid at all that service try handling the scroll event in the directive itself.

Comment: If you have a strong case to believe that you have a memory leak bug you're free to open a new issue in their repo. There are other issues reporting these issues, for example [#7368](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7368), [#5021](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5021), and probably more I'm missing. And finally, just to test, try passing `false` to EventEmitter, like `new EventEmitter(false)`, there are issues with it by being asynchronous, see [#6311](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6311).

Comment: Thanks for you comment. Unfortunatly the project is closed source. I asked for permission to make parts of it open source, so that other people can contribute and investigate if there is a memory leak.

Comment: As for your second comment: I also noticed that the EventEmitter is working asynchronous what caused me already a lot of headache before.

Answer (score 1):

1. Stop using Event Emitter inside services
2. You may use bindings for inter component communication instead of event emitter